# Can't justify text

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, xetex

Let's say we have following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,final,draft]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=2.0cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justifying

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummyy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
\end{document}
```

Expected output:
[image]

Actual output:
[image]

I've spent few hours on it and I still can't figure out how do I actually do justify text in a way like LibreOffice Writer does it.

Comment: You're disabling hyphenation: why?

Comment: `\input{macro_glob}` just generates and error and seems not to be needed. It is normal for paragraphs to start with an indentation, and as you have prevented hyphenation, tex can not justify the lines to the specified width.

Comment: I have to maintain certain format for the text, which forces me to avoid it. So I'm searching for a way to justify text, as Libre, or MS office does : to adds some extra spaces to the first line and move it's last word to the second line.

Comment: If you really want no hyphenation add `\sloppy` which tells latex to give up its normal standards and over-stretch interword white space. But don't do that:-)

Comment: David Carlisle, THANKS A LOT! Add it to your answer. I'll accept it. Yes, I know it's not how normal text should look like, but that's how my report must look like((

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ^^^^ But please keep the warning ;-)

Comment: Sure) At I don't think I'm gonna use it document-wide, but it's a point to start further investigation from.

Comment: @Farrel added:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Justified paragraphs are normally set with indentation and hyphenation using a suitable set of hyphenation patterns:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,final,draft]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=2.0cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}


\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummyy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
\end{document}
```

The amount of indentation is set by for example

```
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
```

which will make no indent, or you could look at the `parskip` package.

If you really want no hyphenation add `\sloppy` which tells latex to give up its normal standards and over-stretch interword white space. But don't do that:-)